# How do I highlight and change a part of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, getselection

I have a textarea where when the user selects and presses enter I want it to change to something else. For example I have a textarea, when a user selects something like NY, I want those two letters to change to NY

**[Here's a fiddle but I'm lost](http://jsfiddle.net/JxyEj/)**

I have something like :

```
$('textarea').html('I live in NY and it\'s a great place to live');
$(window).click(function(){
        var selection = selectedText();
        console.log(selection);
    });

function selectedText() {
    var ret = '';
    if (window.getSelection){
        ret = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        ret = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        ret = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I don't know where to check to see if it's from a textarea or from somewhere else, and I don't know how to change a specific part of a textarea's text

Comment: "when a user selects something like NY, I want those two letters to change to NY." Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of cross browser nuances when it comes to text selection. There are several jQuery plugins trying to deal with this. I'd recommend using [a-tools](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools). I've used it in the past, and it works as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :

[Finding selection start and end position in a textarea](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/finding-selection-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-in-internet-explorer/)

Also i just tested this and it works (it returns the selected text , so you can modify it and assign the value back to the textarea

Ref : http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?p=235174&postcount=5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--//
  function selectedText(input){
    if(document.selection && document.selection.createRange().text != ''){ // IS IE
       alert(document.selection.createRange().text);
    }

    else{ // Not IE.. assume Mozilla?
       var startPos = input.selectionStart;
       var endPos = input.selectionEnd;
           alert(input.value.substring(startPos, endPos))    
   }
 }
 //-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="reportForm">
<textarea name="report">this is a test</textarea>
<button onclick="selectedText(this.form.report)">Alert Selection</button>
</form>
```